# how to remove this image?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, pages

How to remove this picture. I did not find any option to remove this picture
https://www.eod.com.np/wordpress/product-category/software/

[image: find picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find these images in the Wordpress widget section.
https://www.eod.com.np/wordpress/wp-admin/widgets.php.

please check and let me know if this solution worked for you or not.if not then please give me a screenshot of the widget screen I will definitely help you.
Thanks.

Comment: how to remove this picture  from  https://www.eod.com.np/wordpress/shop/                                                https://send.firefox.com/download/a5a5d8d1f0c9794b/#3bpm26DxPoHLj9vJOv08Yw ( the link of the photo)

Comment: you can change this image from  https://www.eod.com.np/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=_options&tab=14
**option name: Banner image in shop pages**